# How to update list view from grid view in android

Tags: android, listview, gridview

How can i update list view from grid view which is inside the listview.
i.e;

```
 listview{
      textview;
      checkbox;
      gridview{
               imageview;
                checkbox;
               };
   }
```

Upon checking the checkbox from grid view, it should update the check box of listview. how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

An idea:

1) In `gridview adapter`, you can use the tag attribute of `checkbox` to store the item position.

2) Create a method on `listview adapter`, it will be called from `click` event of your `checkbox`. Implement your logical to check the `listview` `checkbox`. Don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, then listview will be updated.

3) Call method above, using the tag stored to evaluate how item will be updated.

I hope this helps